# is there a z-index equivalent for frames?

Tags: html, iframe

Here's my problem:

I have two frames, one on top of the other. The top one contains the menu and the drop-down part of the menu gets covered by the lower frame. How would I go about fixing this?

Side question: should I use frames or iframes?

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Dont use frames.  Use divs for layout.

Comment: I'd like to include an mp3 player though...

Comment: you can still use divs for your mp3 player :)

Comment: Ya, but won't the song start over when a new page is reloaded? I want a solution that allows me to navigate through the site without interrupting the mp3 player.

Comment: That's what Ajax (pardon the buzz word) allows you to do: partial page update.  On the other hand, even if you use frame or iframe, if a new page is loaded, your mp3 in the frame/iframe will be gone anyway.  As an alternative to using div, you could just pop up a new browser window that contains your mp3 player.

Comment: 'Aight, I won't go with the frames. Are they deprecated? Thanks guys.

@Khnle's answer: Sorry, I meant if a different frame loaded new information, the mp3 player would continue uninterrupted, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using frames you can't have content from one overlapping the other. To make the menu system work you will need to embed the menu elements in the bottom frame then have the top frame call events to the bottom frame to show the menus, but really don't do it this way.

Design the site around changing out just the content you need you may be able to achieve the same effect using jquery and the load function that could allow your basic nav to stay put and just keep reloading a main content area. Also your mp3 should be fine then.